# How do you copy files into amazon ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have configured a Ubuntu instance in EC2 and have got it running. I am also able to use the ssh command and login into that machine.

What would be the procedure to copy files (e.g. jboss application server, MySQL 5.5 server) into the EC2 instance. How can I access the jboss server instance URL which is running on the EC2 instance (Is it `http://<remoteec2-instance:port/myapp`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You typically install server software like that using a package manager. In Ubuntu, the package manager is `apt`.

Ex:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

As for copying files in general, there are a million ways to copy files from one computer (yours) to another (the EC2 instance):

- FTP
- SFTP
- SCP
- Rsync
- Put them in a source control repo and checkout/clone the rep
- Wget them from a URL

...etc. Aside from possibly opening ports in your EC2 security group settings, nothing you do with this server will be different than if you installed Ubuntu on a computer in your own home. So you don't need to include "on EC2" in your questions/searches. Just read Ubuntu and general Linux documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by Dan, if you need to copy files from your local machine, I'd suggest [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) - gives you easy, secure file transfer (with no need for opening extra ports in your Security Group).